# Transparent objects scheduling - Unity 3D - VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, depth-buffer

I have two transparent objects with the same shader. I can dynamically change their Opacity at runtime.

The problem is an object can hide an other when I change his opacity because of their RendererQueue.

[You see that the Red object is semitransparent but hide the grey object (max opacity for it).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0fRT.png)

But if I approach the camera to the objets, that's work ! Why ? How ? Can I change that ?

Thanks